# How can I create a Table with two Foreign Key References to one other Table via UCanAccess?

Tags: java, ucanaccess

To build the References direct in MS-Access is no Problem.
To do it with UCanAccess results in a "net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException:...".

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://e:/TestDB.accdb;memory=true");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
//
String tableToBeReferenced = "PersonsTable";
String tableWithTheReferences = "RelationShipsTable";

try {// Tidy up
 statement.execute("DROP TABLE " + tableWithTheReferences);
} catch (Exception exeption) {}
try {// Tidy up
 statement.execute("DROP TABLE " + tableToBeReferenced);
} catch (Exception exeption) {}

statement.execute("CREATE TABLE " + tableToBeReferenced + "(ID autoincrement NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"//
    + "Name VARCHAR(255)"//
    + ")");

statement.execute("CREATE TABLE " + tableWithTheReferences + "(ID LONG NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"//
    + "RelationShip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FRIENDS',"//
    + "Person1Id LONG NOT NULL,"//
    + "Person2Id LONG NOT NULL)");

// reference #1
statement.execute("ALTER TABLE " + tableWithTheReferences + //
    " ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_KEY_1 FOREIGN KEY (Person1Id) REFERENCES " //
    + tableToBeReferenced + "(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE");

// reference #2
statement.execute("ALTER TABLE " + tableWithTheReferences + //
    " ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN_KEY_2 FOREIGN KEY (Person2Id) REFERENCES " //
    + tableToBeReferenced + "(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE");
```

If I create only the first Reference it works.
If I create only the second Reference it works.

But when I try to build both References it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce the issue under UCanAccess 4.0.3. Neither HSQLDB nor Jackcess has a problem with creating two independent FK relationships between the same two tables, so it looks like it might be a bug in UCanAccess. I will report the issue to the UCanAccess development team and update this answer with any news.

Update:

A fix for this issue has been implemented and will be included in the UCanAccess 4.0.4 release.

Comment: I have installed the fixed UCanAccess 4.0.4 Version, and it works fine for my given Example.
BUT in my Application I have "Add Foreign Key" Commands, that have Constraints with non explicit Name.
In this Case the Bug is still existant.
For a quick fix I changed my Application Code. Now I use only named Constraints.
But I think it would be better to fix the UCanAccess that it can process also Constraints that have no Name.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will not work since you have "ON DELETE CASCADE" for both your foreign keys.

Comment: No, that does not appear to be the problem. UCanAccess uses HSQLDB as its backing database and HSQLDB is able to create both relationships with ON DELETE CASCADE.